# Daily Reminder - Journey Builder or Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a daily email that will be going out (it has some dynamic fields on it - thanks again to those that helped).

The email will go out as a daily reminder for them to visit a landing page to re-enter a contest.
The only way out is if they click a button to 'Stop Receiving the Reminders' or by unsubscribing.

Would I be better off having a Journey where the re-entry criteria allows them to exit and re-enter?

Or would I be better off using automation studio for an email send?  Am I able to track a link click in that?  If they do click to 'stop receiving reminders' I want to pull them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually would do this as an automation as it is simpler and easier to maintain and edit.

Automation would be:

1. Query - Suppression list
2. Email Send

The query would be there to gather your link clicks for 'Stop receiving the reminders' from your email/landing page. If you are using API from the landing page, this step can be skipped.

You can gather these link clicks either through API ([REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) or [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_data_to_data_extension_object.htm)) on the landing page (or [AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm)/[SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionUpsertDE.htm) if hosted on SFMC) or if it needs to be based on the click in the  email, you can use the [_Click dataview](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_click/) to gather this info.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _Click
WHERE LinkName = {{YourAlias}}
```

To use the Click query, it would be best to utilize an 'alias' on the link and then use that in a where statement. If this is not possible, you can try to query based on URL or some other unique identifier for this link.

Whether through the API or Query, you would then put this information into a DE that would act as either a [suppression](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/) or [exclusion](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/exclusion_list/) list inside your User Initiated Send.

This way it will not unsubscribe the person in any way (which I believe is your goal), but it will prevent that person from receiving any more of these messages.